# How to use type check in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, typechecking

In Kotlin doc, type check use `is` but when I write this code

```
var a="hello"
if (a is String) print(a)
```

There is a warning

```
warning: check for instance is always 'true'
if (a is String) print(a)
    ^
```

Thank you very much for all answers.

Comment: In this code, `a` will always be a string. That's what the compiler tells you. But you can use it in situations like this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts

Comment: Well it is always a string.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `"hello"` is a [`String` literal](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-literals). In Kotlin, even when you omit the type for a variable, its type is inferred. The compiler infers the type for `var a` from the initializer expression, and so the type of `a` is `String`. The warning you are getting means that the expression `a` that you check is always a `String`.

Your variable declaration is equivalent to `var a: String = "hello"`, i.e. the variable may only reference a `String`, assigning any other type is not allowed.

For example, if you change the variable declaration to `var a: Any = "hello"`, there will be no warning since the variable now may hold an instance of any type, not just a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to use type check by learning from Swift

```
open class fruit {}
class banana: fruit() {}

fun test( a: fruit ) {
    if (a is banana) print("ok")
}

test(banana())
```

Comment: That's good, but how does this answer your own question  about the warning?